# How to limit text within a set padding/margin and move the remaining content to the next line?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to set the `padding-left` and `padding-right` only on the `span`  *subDataTitle* element of 20px left and right. I want the text to move to a new line if the text is more than the padding. For instance, here is a diagram of what I am seeing: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whDpe.png) .

As you can see, currently there isn't a 20px padding left and right on the diagram. When I set the padding, I am seeing the 20px space on the left but on the right, the padding is happening at the end of the "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" text. Also the content is not moving to the next line. How can I fix this? This is what I am trying to achieve: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb25F.png). There should be 20px spacing on both left and right side of the element.

```
<div class="DataBox">
    <div class="diagram">
        <h3 class="dataNumber">
            0000,000A
            <span class="subDataTitle">BQETFVXRBNTLDGBNCQIHTVHGHWEDSS ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.subDataTitle{
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` tag has to be a block element. So, The `subDataTitle` class should have a `width` for the block. The text inside the `span` will be wrapped if we set a width size for the `span` element.

Now, the CSS of the `subDataTitle` class is like below,

```
.subDataTitle{
  display: block;
  width: 80px; // use size on your demand
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**MAGIC TRICK**

Use only `width: 75ch` instead of `width: 80px` and `word-wrap: break-word`. You can wrapped the long texts easily. Special thanks to @Kiruna mentioned in comment.

Comment: What do you think of using `ch` as unit of width for text?
As a rule of thumb, we usually do `width: 75ch` for text